# Asynchronous reading XML in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have problem while trying to read XML data from string asynchronous in Blazor. It's just freeze browser for couple seconds while reading. I wonder how to do it asynchronous to get nice progress for validation.
Here is my implementation.

```
<RadzenButton Visible="true" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Click="@(async () => await ValidateAsync())">Waliduj Async</RadzenButton>

    private async Task ValidateAsync()
    {
        await using var timer = new Timer(_ => InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()));
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        progress = 0;
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlData);
            settings.Async = true;

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    progress++;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

P.S. This is my first stackoverflow question so feel free to correct me if construction of question is incorrect

Comment: This is Blazor Server-side with server interactivity, right?  Add the correct tags.

Comment: And in what ballpark is the end value of progress?

Comment: What exactly is xmlData?

Comment: @ℍℍ This is webassembly, progress is just a concept what i want to do in this loop, xmlData is a string xmlData = string.Empty; and it's data is provided in other part of code

Comment: OK, I assumed it was a stream. You can't read async from a string. You might as well use  Async=false then. And the Delay(1) trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK but I suspect that ReadAsync() is executing synchronously most of the time.

**Edit:** the input is a string so Async is not even possible. ReadAsync() is the same as Read().

As an experiment, give the UI some breathing space:

```
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    progress++;
    await Task.Delay(1);
}
```

This will increase the total execution time. When it works you can try only calling it when `progress % N == 0`

Comment: [Respectfully] Are your sure the code is OK?  I've just plugged a simplified version into SharpLab to check out the constructed state machine.   Isn't `progress++` part of the completion and only runs once when we have a result for `ReadAsync`?

Comment: Yes, I assume that ReadAsync() will execute many times. In the end progress should hold a count of the elements.  Note that this code doesn't actually use the xml.

Comment: I read this totally wrong last night and went out left field while half asleep.  The `while` suggests the OP expects `ReadAsync` to loop.  The code doesn't really make sense!

Comment: Look up Read{Async} on the reader. It reads 'the next element' and returns a bool. The while does loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I just did some reading.  I don't do much file stuff these days.